# How do I combine active button and hover?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a darker color then button class is already active and when I hover on it with a mouse like shown on the screenshot. Which CSS style code should I write to make a darker color then two conditions are fulfilled? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine a `.active` class with a `:hover` pseudo-class in your CSS code like below. The `.active` class will darken the element and the `:hover` combined to `.active` will darken it even more.

```css
button.active{
  background-color:#aaa;
}
button.active:hover{ /* combine two conditions */
  background-color:#999;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="active">An active button</button>
<button type="button" class="">A normal button</button>
```

Comment: He/She is a new programmer, i dont think showing him jqeury will help him.

Comment: This could be accomplished in vanilla javascript without the unnecessary jQuery!

Comment: I'm sorry, the jQuery was only here to provide a better snippet. I've edited my answer, hoping my explanations are enough to understand that selectors can be combined in CSS (see the CSS part of the snippet)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the color of the button while your mouse is on it try this

html =

```
<div class="container"
<a href ="#">  Hover me </a>
</div>
```

then you put this in your css to make it do something when you hover on it

css =

```
.container a:hover{
    background: #ddd;
}
```

this is a easy way to do it, there are way more of these functions you can try, such as `:visited`

```css
.container a:hover{
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a href ="#">  Hover me </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't mean that. The button is already activated and gray, I want to hover It and it gets grayer then two conditions are fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

suppose we have the following html code

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li class="active">Lorem Ipsum</li>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

the css should be

```css
li:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
li.active{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
li.active:hover{

}
```

Answer (score -1):

`.class:hover:active {
    //rules
}`

But most of the time, you wouldn't want to use a pseudo class like :active to achieve the desired style since :active only applies to html that's being clicked. You may have to add an additional class by javascript (for example: 'active, etc') and then use CSS to apply the "triggered" class like so.

`.class.active:hover {
    //rules
}`